# How can I include a whitespace in a variable's value in Airflow while setting it through command line?

Tags: airflow

I am trying to set a variable in Airflow, which includes a white space in its value.
None of the below commands work.

```
/home/airflow/exec airflow  variables -s var_name "var value"
/home/airflow/exec airflow  variables -s var_name 'var value'
/home/airflow/exec airflow  variables -s var_name var value
```

Error -

```
airflow: error: unrecognized arguments: value
```

It seems to be splitting words based on whitespaces. How can I work around this?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a possible bug, you could log a JIRA ticket for someone to investigate. Meanwhile, do you have access to the Airflow Webserver UI?

You can configure variables from the `Admin` -> `Variables` UI.
I have tested there and it allows me to add a 'var value' including the whitespace.

Edit: Not a bug - I am able to add the variable using the following command: `airflow  variables -s var_name "var value"` and it shows up fine in the UI.

You seem to be using a wrapper script of some sort `/home/airflow/exec` - can you remove that? It probably isn't unpacking the arguments properly

Comment: I had a similar issue, but on AWS Managed Airflow (MWAA) - its CLI-over-HTTP API (which is really an HTTP interface to Airflow's CLI) seems to expect Airflow variable values to be enclosed within double quotes if they contain any blanks.